# How do you return all data in SQL based on specific number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column "Country" in "Address" table.

I want to return only data for those countries that have 10 rows.

For example, if France has 10 rows (and other countries) I want to see them. If I have Italy with only 9 records I don't want to see it.

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one group per country, and then demand that the group has 10 rows:

```
select  Country
from    Address
group by
        Country
having  count(*) = 10
```

To return all rows with those countries, you can use a subquery:

```
select  *
from    Address
where   Country in
        (
        select  Country
        from    Address
        group by
                Country
        having  count(*) = 10
        )
```